# how to change background color for selected item in tabBarController

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, tabbarcontroller

I tried to change background, the only thing that changed was the image and label color, I want the background itself to change into a different color.

Example:

[image: imgExampleTabBarController]

Does someone know how to make this change?

Answer (score 2):

In your `UITabBarController` add the following code:

```
override func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {

    let removeSelectedBackground = {
        tabBar.subviews.filter({ $0.layer.name == "TabBackgroundView" }).first?.removeFromSuperview()
    }

    let addSelectedBackground = { (bgColour: UIColor) in
        let tabIndex = CGFloat(tabBar.items!.index(of: item)!)
        let tabWidth = tabBar.bounds.width / CGFloat(tabBar.items!.count)
        let bgView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: tabWidth * tabIndex, y: 0, width: tabWidth, height: tabBar.bounds.height))
        bgView.backgroundColor = bgColour
        bgView.layer.name = "TabBackgroundView"
        tabBar.insertSubview(bgView, at: 0)
    }

    removeSelectedBackground()
    addSelectedBackground(UIColor.green)
}
```

It inserts a `green` view wherever the selected tab is.. You can also make it respect `safeAreaInsets` too.. Now whenever you select a tab, it removes the selected background view from the `UITabBar` and adds a new one at the right position. You can re-use the same view every time if you like or animate from the old position to the new one.. whatever you feel like. You can identify views by tag instead of layer name but that's just personal preferences.

Comment: How can i set first tab as selected in initial loading time ?

Answer (score 0):

Why not have two images for each tabBarItem where one image is for **default** state, and the other for **selected** state. In your case all white for selected state, and green for default.

You can either set these images for your `UIBarItem` via the store property of the UIBarItem `var selectedImage: UIImage? { get set }` or by constructor/initializer `init(title: String?, image: UIImage?, selectedImage: UIImage?)`.

Comment: Thanks, I will make an image with white background and the icon in the center

Answer (score -1):

You could probably try something like:

```
UITabBar.appearance().backgroundColor = .white
UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = .green // or whatever your green is
```

That would make all tab bars in your application default to those colours when they're instantiated.

Note: I haven't tested this.